# Vagrant with private network IP address conflict

Tags: networking, ip, vagrant

I use vagrant with VirtualBox to set up a development environment. The goal is to allow developers create their own development environment easily.

Because we want to use NFS, we have to use private network provision.

The Vagrant file specifies a private network ip 192.168.33.33. I know this can be any IP address as long as it does not collide with other device in the same network.

I am not experienced in networking. My question is that if two developers both are trying to 'vagrant up' at the same time in the office, and both run using the given 192.168.33.33 ip address , will it collide ?

The office router IP is 198.168.20.1 (255.255.255.0) , instead of 192.168.33.1, would this make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question after testing it by myself.

I've set up 3 imac running at the same time, no problem, no collision.

This is good, because I can simply take the vagrant file under source control and have it used by every one.

Comment: Why doesn't it collide? Aren't they both in the same LAN space?

Comment: Same LAN, same office, no problem. I guess the private network is simply a network between the hose and vagrant servers